# PowerShell pass script argument to configurate function

Tags: powershell

I have a global

```
function log( [string] $message, $logType = 'console' ){}
log( 'hello' );
```

It write logs to console by default. And i want to configure it by command line argument to keep all calls the same, but with another logging type. function can take or arguments, or command line parameters. and i want to mix them

Answer (score 0):

```
function log($message,$logtype = 'console'){
    switch ($logtype){
        'console' {Write-Host $message}
        'verbose' {Write-Verbose $message}
        'file' {Out-File $message $path}
        default {$message}
    }
}
log 'FOO' 'verbose'
```

For the $logtype parameter you might want to set Mandatory to $false. [Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx)